# Selenium Remote Webdriver idle / stuck after click()

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I'm running my JBehave tests against a Remote Selenium Webdriver running on a grid. The thing is, the Remote Webdriver goes idle when I'm clicking a specific tab in my interface. The code I use to click is:

```
getDriver().findElement(By.linkText(link)).click();
```

After that, the Remote Webdriver doesn't respond anymore. Even debugging after this line and just getting the page source doesn't respond.

Fun facts:

1. **Running a local Webdriver does work :S**
2. This click() method is also used for numerous other stories / scenario's

Tried all the tips & tricks I could find:

1. Use xpath instead of linktext for finding the element
2. Debugging (ended up in hanging up my IntelliJ)
3. Setting the firefox preference "webdriver.load.strategy" to "unstable"

The page that is being loaded after this click holds an iframe (I know, I know), could that pose a problem?

If someone could just help me a bit further. I can't even debug the problem now :-(

I'm running against a v2.46.0 Selenium Remote Webdriver with a firefox browser v38.0.

---

The stack trace I'm getting after a while:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$RunningStoriesFailed: Failures in running stories: ReportsCount[stories=1,storiesNotAllowed=0,storiesPending=0,scenarios=1,scenariosFailed=1,scenariosNotAllowed=0,scenariosPending=0,stepsFailed=2]
    at de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitReportingRunner.run(JUnitReportingRunner.java:80)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$RunningStoriesFailed: Failures in running stories: ReportsCount[stories=1,storiesNotAllowed=0,storiesPending=0,scenarios=1,scenariosFailed=1,scenariosNotAllowed=0,scenariosPending=0,stepsFailed=2]
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$ThrowingRunningStoriesFailed.handleFailures(Embedder.java:525)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.handleFailures(Embedder.java:269)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.generateReportsView(Embedder.java:256)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.generateReportsView(Embedder.java:237)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Embedder.java:213)
    at de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitReportingRunner.run(JUnitReportingRunner.java:78)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the issue :-)

The page that is being opened tries to connect to a map server that it can't reach.

Apparently, if a situation like this arises Selenium doesn't throw a timeout error of the connection that has failed to establish, but throws the nothing-I-can-derive-from-stacktrace posted above.

Leaving it here for people getting the same behavior / errors and not thinking about connection problems either 0:-)